# NInject doesn't resolve a specific dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I've been working with NInject in my Wep API2 project without problems so far, but I'm struggling with a weird situation now.

I have a controller that receives 3 parameters for setting it's dependencies. The constructor looks like this:

```
public UsersController(IUsersServices userServices, IConfigurationServices configServices, IUsersAPIProxy usersProxy) 
{
    this.configServices = configServices;
    this.userServices = userServices;
    this.usersProxy = usersProxy;
 }
```

The dependency that can´t be resolved is the latest one: IUsersAPIProxy. There are no issues with the other 2.
Off course, the bindings for the dependencies are defined, like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IUsersAPIProxy>().To<UsersAPIProxy>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUsersServices>().To<UsersServices>().InRequestScope(); 
kernel.Bind<IConfigurationServices>().To<ConfigurationServices>().InRequestScope();
```

The IUsersAPIProxy interface is very simple:

```
public interface IUsersAPIProxy
{
    UserModel ReadUser(string loginName);
    IEnumerable<UserModel> ReadAllUsers();
}
```

The class UsersApiProxy doesn't have any dependencies that need to be injected:

```
public class UsersAPIProxy : APIProxyBase, IUsersAPIProxy
{
    public IEnumerable<UserModel> ReadAllUsers()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("sec/users2/");           
        IRestResponse<List<UserModel>> response = client.Execute<List<UserModel>>(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return response.Data;

        throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("There was an error when trying to retrieve the users. Response content: {0}"));
    }

    public UserModel ReadUser(string loginName)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("sec/users2/{loginName}");
        request.AddUrlSegment("loginName", loginName);
        IRestResponse<UserModel> response = client.Execute<UserModel>(request);

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return response.Data;

        throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("There was an error when trying to retrieve data for user {0}. Response content: {1}", loginName, response.Content));
    }
}
```

Its base class is nothing special either:

```
public class APIProxyBase
{
   protected RestClient client = null;

    public APIProxyBase()
    {
        client = new RestClient("http://myHost:MyPort/"); 
    }
}
```

For a reason I don't know if I remove the IUsersAPIProxy parameter from the controller's constructor, it works as expected. The weird thing is that it only happens with this dependency. Changing the parameter to a different position of course that won't help. Also, the other interfaces and classes that actually work are much more complex.
One thing worth to mention is that the types that work are defined at a different dll that the types that don't work. Needless to say that the web api is correctly referencing both dlls.
The exception I get is as follows:

**Message:**
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'UsersController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

**Stack Trace:**
   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

Could someone point me to the right direction please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the actual error dump.

Comment: Also, please post the Ninject bindings for the other two parameters.

Comment: Hi!! The actuall error dump is as follows: "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'UsersController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

Comment: The bindings that work are the same, basically:      

kernel.Bind<IUsersServices>().To<UsersServices>().InRequestScope(); 
kernel.Bind<IConfigurationServices>().To<ConfigurationServices>().InRequestScope();

Comment: Please post the ENTIRE error dump, not just the portions that you think could help. In other words, please post the entire stack. Please edit your question instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: Are you working with .Net Full Framework? (4.6) or Asp Net Core (1.1 or 2.0)?

Comment: I edited the question to include the information requested. I'm working with the full framework (.Net 4.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Its base class is nothing special either:

```
public class APIProxyBase
{
    protected RestClient client = null;

    public APIProxyBase()
    {
        client = new RestClient("http://myHost:MyPort/"); 
    }
}
```

I think you are mistaken about this - there is something special going on here. You are newing up a dependency during the *construction* phase of your application. This dependency may rely on *runtime* data in order to function (e.g. `HttpContext`), which isn't available at application startup.

To test out this theory, comment the line that instantiates `RestClient` to see if your dependency is injected.

```
public class APIProxyBase
{
    protected RestClient client = null;

    public APIProxyBase()
    {
        //client = new RestClient("http://myHost:MyPort/"); 
    }
}
```

It's possible that the object fails to instantiate due to an error that is being swallowed by Ninject.

Comment: It's entirely possible. He could also inject the `RestClient` object (e.g. interface). That would help visualize the dependency chain and construction too and would probably result in a more detailed error dump.

Comment: Excellent Guys, I will try that out and let you know as soon as I can. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hello NightOwI888, It was exactly as you said, you guys saved my day!! Thanks!!